# WebGl - not loaded texture

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I receive an error: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at file:///C:/Users/.../img.jpg may not be loaded.

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
    var geometry, material, mesh;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
        camera.position.z = 1000;

        geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 300, 300, 300 );
        material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img.jpg')
        });

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( mesh );

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.setClearColorHex( 0xFFF8DC, 1 );

        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    }

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        mesh.rotation.x += 0.02;
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }
```

Comment: I don't know if that works for local images, but according to [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/ImageUtils), you can add `THREE.ImageUrils.crossOrigin = '';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run a simple static content server called [mongoose](http://cesanta.com/mongoose.shtml) locally on my development machine. Simply point it to the folder that contains your project and you can load the page without worrying about any cross site scripting/origin issues,

Answer (score 1):

You can use a converter to binary code image http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pHKyw physical file to avoid problems. 
or you can upload one server, this failure happens because you're not running on a server and the file can not be found.

for example:

original

```
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img.jpg')
```

replace

```
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU ... ')
```

Comment: thanks! Why work here? http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-webgl-texture-with-three-js/