# webgl three.js - how to display a sprite ? Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined at SpritePlugin.render

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am a begginer with three.js.

I tried the code found here: [Creating-a-scene](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene)

Then I tried to add a sprite with the code found here:
[Sprite](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/Sprite)

But I couldn't make it work as I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at SpritePlugin.render (three.js:6973)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:21007)
    at render (sprite.html:43)
```

**The html file is there:**
http://www.planetarium2016.com/sprite.html

Where is my mistake ? Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            // instantiate a loader
            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            //allow cross origin loading
                //loader.crossOrigin = '';
            // load a resource
            loader.load("https://codefisher.org/static/images/pastel-svg/256/bullet-star.png");
            var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: loader, color: 0xffffff } );
            var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
            sprite.scale.set(200, 200, 1);
            scene.add( sprite );
            camera.position.z = 2;
            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the lines below would fix the error.

```
var spriteMap = loader.load("https://codefisher.org/static/images/pastel-svg/256/bullet-star.png");
var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: spriteMap, color: 0xffffff } );
```

And `requestAnimationFrame` is necessary. Let's just keep the `render` function as it used to be.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that on Friday.

Comment: You made sure keeping this line? ```var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();```

Comment: I guess I wrote a mistake. Now I get the following errors : `DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at https://codefisher.org/static/images/pastel-svg/256/bullet-star.png may not be loaded.` and `[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-056CCFE8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGenerateMipmap: Can not generate mips` and `[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-056CCFE8]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering.`

Comment: it is a 256x256 png image though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, even if it is said to be very easy, showing a simple sprite with three.js and webGL is quite an issue.

I met many errors and I needed to combine two solutions to suceed:

- [WebGl - not loaded texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370492/webgl-not-loaded-texture)
- [Three.js - how to wait for a image to be loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43733088/three-js-how-to-wait-for-a-image-to-be-loaded)

  1. if you don't run on a server, the image needed to be converted to binary
  2. you need to wait for the image to be loaded to proceed.

Finally, the following code works:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
            camera.position.set(0, 10, 100);
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            var a = 5;
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-a, 0, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, a, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(a, 0, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -a));

            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);

            scene.add(line);

            var img = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAIAAACQkWg2AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAABISURBVDhPzc1bCgAgCETR9r9poxynEHoIEp0vLS4WCWpBMfq09yYI8QFuTfBhlgFXHSgj4KB0pYzAwYfx+9FVgFv92ifBIFIBJq9zqYwecEQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            var spriteMaterial;
            loader.load(img,
                function(texture)
                    {
                        spriteMaterial.map = texture;
                        spriteMaterial.needsUpdate = true;
                    }

                );
            var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
            sprite.scale.set(6, 6, 1);
            sprite.position.set( 0, 6, -6 );
            scene.add( sprite );

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```