# Three.js - how to wait for a image to be loaded?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I load an image to show a sprite.

But it seems that the code proceeds before the image is fully load:

- [dart:web_gl: RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954036/dartweb-gl-render-warning-texture-bound-to-texture-unit-0-is-not-renderable)
- [WebGL - wait for texture to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722247/webgl-wait-for-texture-to-load/19748905#19748905)

But I don't know how to wait for the image to be fully loaded using Threejs.
May I have some help?

The code can be tested here : http://www.planetarium2016.com/sprite.html

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js"></script>
        <script>
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
            camera.position.set(0, 10, 100);
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10, 0, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -10));

            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);

            scene.add(line);

            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            var spriteMap = loader.load("https://codefisher.org/static/images/pastel-svg/256/bullet-star.png");

            //+-----------------------------------------------------------+
            //|   I need here to wait for the image to be fully loaded    |
            //|   This cheat is fool: while (spriteMap.image.width == 0); |
            //+-----------------------------------------------------------+

            var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: spriteMap, color: 0xffffff } );
            var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
            sprite.scale.set(256, 256, 1);
            sprite.position.set( 0, 0, 10 );
            scene.add( sprite );

            //camera.position.z = 2;

            var render = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame( render );
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
            render();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[THREE JS TextureLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010165/three-js-textureloader) is a little bit old...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [THREE JS TextureLoader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010165/three-js-textureloader)

Comment: var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.load(url,function(){
  //to do logic here.
});
see the TextureLoader Class document

Comment: @darren-sweeney These old question and answers are obsolete

Comment: @kian that's right: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader

Comment: @Pierre-LouisDeschamps Ah ok, my point was mainly to highlight `.load` callback, which you're now using

Comment: @darren-sweeney well, your comment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010165/three-js-textureloader helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 7):

I would solve this by using JavaScript promises. I separated your three.js code into two main functions, one for initialization and one for animation with requestAnimationFrame. It's more readable this way especially if you intend to perform an async task:

```
        var scene;
        var camera;
        var renderer;

        var spriteMap;

        var loaderPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            function loadDone(x) {
                console.log("loader successfully completed loading task");
                resolve(x); // it went ok!
            }
            var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            loader.load("https://codefisher.org/static/images/pastel-svg/256/bullet-star.png", loadDone);
        });

        loaderPromise.
            then(function(response) {
                spriteMap = response; //assign loaded image data to a variable
                init(); //initialize the render
                requestAnimationFrame( render );
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });

        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);

            camera.position.set(0, 10, 100);
            camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-10, 0, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 10, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 0));
            geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -10));

            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
            scene.add(line);

            var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: spriteMap, color: 0xffffff } );
            var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
            sprite.scale.set(256, 256, 1);
            sprite.position.set( 0, 0, 10 );
            scene.add( sprite );
        }

        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
        }
```

Comment: How can this be extended to a loader that will be used to load multiple objects?

Comment: Create an array of objects and use Promise.all to wait for all of them to load before calling the init() method.

Answer (score 0):

solution here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/loaders/TextureLoader

this is the code to solve my problem:

```
        var url = "https://codefisher.org/static/images/pastel-svg/256/bullet-star.png";
        var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        var spriteMaterial;
        loader.load(url,
            function(texture)
                {
                    spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: texture, color: 0x0000ff } );
                }

            );
        var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial );
```

Comment: thanks for acknowledgment  but there is gap in this code. loader.load(url,  function(texture)  { spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: texture, color: 0x0000ff } );  }  );   var sprite = new THREE.Sprite( spriteMaterial ); //sprteMaterial might be undefined here. Instead do this var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {  color: 0x0000ff } );
loader.load(url,
            function(texture)
                {
                    spriteMaterial.map = texture;
                    spriteMaterial.needsUpdate = true;
                }

            );

Comment: You are right: I could only show a white square instead of the star.png. But doing your code, I get the same errors as when I didn't wait for the image to be loaded: http://www.planetarium2016.com/sprite.html

Comment: so is this warking or not ? please accept your own answer if yes

Comment: Can't tell. It was in 2017! I have to work on a similar code in 2022. I will test it again and update this thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
loader.load(
    'img/url/img.png',
    function ( map ) {
        // map var is your image                                                                      
    }, 
    function ( xhr ) {                                                                                    
        if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {                                                                                       
           console.log( 'percent: ' + (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) );                                                                                   
        }
    },
    function ( err ) {                                                                                      
       console.log( 'An error happened' );
    }
);
```

THREE 73